# How to get node value / innerHTML with XPath?

Tags: xml, parsing, xpath, html-parsing

I have a XPath to select to a class I want: `//div[@class='myclass']`. But it returns me the whole div (with the `<div class='myclass'>` also, but I would like to return only the contents of this tag without the tag itself. How can I do it?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

With xpath, the thing you will get returned is the last thing in the path that is not a condition. What that means? Well, conditions are the stuff between `[]`'s (but you already knew that) and yours reads like *pathElement[**that has a 'class' attribute with value 'my class'**]*. The pathElement comes directly before the `[`.

All the stuff outside of `[]`'s then is the path, so in `//a/b/c[@blah='bleh']/d` *a*, *b*, *c* and *d* are all path elements, *blah* is an attribute and *bleh* a literal value. If this path matches it will return you a *d*, the last non-condition thing.

Your particular path returns a (series of) *div*, being the last thing in your xpath's path. This return value thus includes the top-level node(s), *div* in your case, and underneath it (them) all its (their) children. Nodes can be elements or text (or comments, processing instructions, ...).

Underneath a node there can be multiple text nodes, hence the array pOcHa talks about. `x/text()` returns all text that is a direct child of x, `x/node()` returns all child nodes, *including* text.

Answer (score 48):

```
node() = innerXml

text() = innerText
```

both are arrays, so `text()[1]` is a first children text node...

Comment: How would multiple text nodes look like in XML? Would text() return a concatination of all innerTexts that a children of the selected node?

Comment: @CoDEmanX: `<div>text1<span>text2</span>text3</div>` as I said, it is an **array**, so `div/node()[0] == div/text()[0] == text1` node, and `div/node()[1] == span` node, and `div/node()[2] == div/text()[1] == text3` node - you would have to concatenate them yourself (by hand or with a helper function that accepts an array).

Answer (score 10):

<sub>***New answer to an old, frequently asked question:***</sub>

For this XML

```
<div class="myclass">content</div>
```

you can use XPath to select just `content` in one of two ways:

1. **Text Node Selection**

   This XPath,

   ```
   //div[@class='myclass']/text()
   ```

   will select the text node children of the targeted `div` element,
   `content`, as requested.
2. **String Value of an Element**

   This XPath,

   ```
   string(//div[@class='myclass'])
   ```

   will return [string-value](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#dt-string-value) of the targeted `div` element,
   `content`, again as requested.

   Further information: Here's a [note](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#element-nodes) explaining the ***string-values*** of elements:

   > The [string-value](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#dt-string-value) of an element node is the concatenation of the
   >   [string-value](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#dt-string-value)s of all text node [descendants](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#dt-descendants) of the element
   >   node in document order.

Comment: King ... You helped me with string(xpath) 

Answer (score 4):

You can try

```
//div[@class='myclass']/child::*
```

`child::*` selects all element children of the context node [see details](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/)