# Extract HTML out of an element/node

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

Assume there is a string of html...

```
<div class="content">
   This is some test <b>this is bold </b> this is great list of text.
</div>
<div class="content">
   <ul>
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 3</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Now I want to scrape the contents of these 2 elements in a single variable using Scrapy.

```
def parse(self, response):
   hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)

   # this returns all nested elements/nodes except text
   contents = product.select('//div[@class="content"]/*').extract()

   # this returns all nested text except elements/nodes
   contents = product.select('//div[@class="content"]/text()').extract()
```

How can I get whole nested HTML of both elements/nodes as string in a variable?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with `/node()` -- see https://stackoverflow.com/a/10899531/85461 in answer to a similar question.

```
# Returns all child nodes - text as well as elements.
contents = product.select('//div[@class="content"]/node()').extract()
```

Note that `extract()` will return a list, which you can concatenate in the usual way to restore the HTML:

```
html = "\n".join(contents)
```

Answer (score 0):

If speed isn't crucial you can easily do it with BeautifulSoup
http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(response)
contents = soup.findAll("div", {"class":"content"})
for content in contents:
    print content # this is div html
```

Comment: Would prefer to do it with Native support

Answer (score 0):

The following xpath

```
//div[@class="content"]/text()|//div[@class="content"]/b/text()|//div[@class="content"]/ul/li
```

gives the result, since you need to store only two element's data,

```
contents=product.select('//div[@class="content"]/text()|//div[@class="content"]/b/text()|//div[@class="content"]/ul/li').extract()
```

Now,contents have both element's data